# How to export object in TypeScript from Types.ts file

Tags: typescript

I have following declaration in the end of `Types.ts`:

```js
export let selectItemList = {
  selectedInvoiceProvider: new SelectItemData<InvoiceProvider>(
    {
      "-": new SelectItemDataOption<InvoiceProvider>(InvoiceProvider.No),
      Billingo: new SelectItemDataOption<InvoiceProvider>(
        InvoiceProvider.Billingo
      ),
      "szamlazz.hu": new SelectItemDataOption<InvoiceProvider>(
        InvoiceProvider.Szamlazzhu
      ),
    },
    InvoiceProvider.No
  ),
```

But when I save and run I got this error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/Types.ts   Line 0:  Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of
> undefined

If I remove `export` **ALL WORKS, STRANGE**

---

[EDIT]

I tried as Julian Kleine suggested, without any success:

```js
const selectItemList = {
  selectedInvoiceProvider: new SelectItemData<InvoiceProvider>(
    {
      "-": new SelectItemDataOption<InvoiceProvider>(InvoiceProvider.No),
      Billingo: new SelectItemDataOption<InvoiceProvider>(
        InvoiceProvider.Billingo
      ),
      "szamlazz.hu": new SelectItemDataOption<InvoiceProvider>(
        InvoiceProvider.Szamlazzhu
      ),
    },
    InvoiceProvider.No
  ),
  // ...

export { selectItemList };
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the constant first then export it

```js
const myAwesomeValue = ...

export { myAwesomeValue }
```

somewhere else

```js
import { myAwesomeValue } from "..."
```

Comment: I tried your appoach, but does not work, would you check upper? I get same error.

Comment: Which error do you get now? The code is correct, there must be a different issue

Comment: the same: `./src/Types.ts Line 0: Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: There should be an issue within your class then. I don't see any map in your code

Comment: check your constructor function within one of the classes that you are using

Comment: I put here the code, but will check constructor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65848658/what-is-wrong-with-my-generic-classes-in-typescript

Comment: Where are you using a map?